# Is Blood On The Clocktower on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, game-systems

Is this the correct forum for Blood On The Clocktower questions? It's more of a social deduction game, and less of a RPG.

Answer (score 14):

#### No

Because it's not really a roleplaying game, it belongs more on [the Board & Card Games stack](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/). There are already [4 questions about Blood on the Clocktower](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bblood-on-the-clocktower%5D%20is%3Aquestion) there.

Comment: At first sight, that feels weird. The game has neither a board *nor* cards.

Comment: @nvoigt As Exempt-Medic mentioned below, it's basically a variant on Mafia & Werewolf, and some versions of those games do use cards to assign roles.

Comment: There **is** a board and cards, for the Storyteller to determine and communicate roles, and to track the interaction and status between players. The website includes a demonstration video where these are clearly visible. @nvoigt

Comment: I don't think I've ever commented or answered as an authority before, but as the creator and admin of the largest BotC community online, I definitely don't consider BotC an RPG.  Board and Card Games is a much better fit for questions about it - it's mechanically most similar to Werewolf and other circle-style social deduction games: right down to the "informed minority kills at night, uninformed majority votes to execute during the day" basic gameplay loop.  While players certainly _may_ roleplay the characters they get, it's not part of the default game assumptions.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

[image]

Blood on the Clocktower is a classic diceless freeform large-group roleplaying game.  The game instructs you to take on the roles (see: roleplaying) of a bunch of villagers in a gothically named village.  There's a GM.  You're meant to act in character, although it avoids saying to what degree.

This is entirely different to a board game where you don't do any roleplaying.  While there are likely versions of this game where no roleplaying occurs and it's just mechanical interaction/questions/guessing, just like how in D&D you can have a dungeon crawl with absolutely zero roleplaying or IC interaction and just 'I roll to attack' 'pass the chips' etc, the rules clearly indicate roleplaying is meant to occur (just as they do in D&D), there is a setting, there is a GM, etc.  Couldn't be more clearly on topic for this stack.

Comment: At least to me, this game reads as being similar to Mafia/Werewolf/Salem, which are social-deduction style games with roles and a narrator/coordinator. They are on-topic for Board/Card Games Stack, though that doesn't mean they aren't *also* on-topic here, I thought it worth mentioning

Comment: @Exempt-Medic There are ttrpgs very similar to lots of board games and card games, especially in resolution mechanic.  The difference is in the 'rpg', 'role playing game'.  If you're playing roles, it's a roleplaying game.  If you're not, it's a miniatures wargame (or w/e).

Comment: BOTC can be played entirely without roleplaying, it is not a core feature/method/motivation in the game. If the argument for making it on-topic is that the players pretend to take on a role, the entire meaning of the question "is it RPG?" has been completely removed: almost every game is an RPG because almost every game involves taking on a role.

Comment: @Nij that's not what the rules of the game on the website that I read say.  That may be the custom or practice, but I can literally point you to game stores where they play 5e d&d where if you tried to speak in-character the entire room would look at you like you just grew a second head.  If the rules of the game talk about playing roles, it's a roleplaying game.  If they don't, it's not.  That's a fairly simple and applicable distinction.

Comment: It's also a largely pointless one. A significant number of games talk about *"taking on the role of X"* but they are very clearly not RPGs and would not be considered on-topic here.

Comment: Whether it's something we could consider a tabletop RPG is worth exploring, but probably the rhetorical device of asserting it's plain & simple & very clear is not helping that exploration. Our hobby is very much aware the borders get fuzzy and is more than willing to explore them; it's fine for it to be unclear, but we can't explore this if we're not willing to acknowledge there might be some lack of clarity. It's not cut & dry here, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Every argument here could also apply to monopoly - players take the role of businessman; one player manages the bank; you're meant to get as rich as you can. Therefore, I don't think an enumeration like this is sufficient to call it an RPG.

Comment: @Gloweye no player is specifically in the role of referee, the rules do not mention entering the role or playing a role, there is no setting.  The players are only ever referred to as 'players' or 'Bank'.  The difference between a board game and a game with a setting, roles, and an implicit and explicit expectation of playing those roles out is extremely clear cut.